# com.sun.proxy.$Proxy439 cannot be cast to DDLRecordSetLocalService

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I am trying to get all Dynamic Data List (DDL) from Liferay DXP 7.0.2 GA3 but
after I using that code to get all the DDL

```
List<DDLRecordSet> ddlList = DDLRecordSetLocalServiceUtil.getDDLRecordSets(
                com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.QueryUtil.ALL_POS,
                com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
```

I got an error saying

```
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy439 cannot be cast to com.liferay.dynamic.data.lists.service.DDLRecordSetLocalService
```

Java JDK: 1.8.0_251

Gradle Version: 5.6.4

Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DDLRecordSetLocalServiceUtil` (the old compatibility class with static methods) you should have the service injected by OSGi, through `@Reference`.

This can only be done in a `@Component`, but makes it a lot clearer that your code is only called when all the dependencies are properly wired.

But before you do this, you'll need to upgrade to [GA7 and patch](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1). Later, ideally upgrade further and stay on the current version.

Comment: @Ahmed   Olaf is actually saying that there is a timing issue ... when you invoke the static util class the internal Java proxy has not been completely initialized ...when injecting it with osgi, the environment takes care of these kind of things